# How to write xpath for this code

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code
i am not able to find the xpath for this code plz help me

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-title">
            <a href="/MCare_Test/Auhmc/Admin/Operator/List">
            <h3>
                <i class="fa fa-user"/>
                Operators
            </h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the desire element you want ...? ... @href? or text as operators?

Comment: i want to click on Operators link

Comment: //i[@class="fa fa-user"]

Answer (score 0):

Please try below Xpath:-

```
//i[@class='fa fa-user' and contains(.,'Operators')]
```

Please get back to me if still facing any issue :)

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick
`//i[@class="fa fa-user"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below xpath :

```
 //h3[contains(text(),'Operators')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use `driver.findElement(By.xpath("whatever"))` you could instead use `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Operators"))`